# Structures inside unions in c

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, unions

I try to declare the union var char name[20]="Arun"

Error popup up like

[Error] **incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [5]' to 'char [20]**'

I Don't know what can i Do now?

Last one month I can't catch the detail, Please Help me To find out

Comment: Depends about what you will do with the string, copy using `strncpy` can be the best

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Hello Raja Karthikeyan.

It is not related to unions.
The declaration of the name variable is incorrect:

```
char name[] = "Arun";
```

or

```
char name[5];
```

and then assign / copy the "Arun" string into it.

The difference is that at first code of line, the compiler will assign 5+1 (null terminated sign) bytes into the name variable, so you can't declare it as you declared.
If you want to assign the name variable 20 bytes, make it like this:

```
char name[20];
strcpy(name, "Arun");   // don't forget to include <string.h>
```

Comment: Thank You, Finally it's Working Bro. Thanks A lot

Comment: @RajaKarthikeyan - your welcome, if I answered you, please give me a V sign